# How to block a function from being called?

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey, tampermonkey

I'm trying to figure out how to block the magnify function whenever you hover over an item on this page: https://hibid.com/lots?q=cisco&status=OPEN

I see that is is loaded in this script function magnify(o,t,e=""): https://cdn.hibid.com/cdn/pwa/1.15.3.34/scripts.6a4acc6484fe8adf.js

Any help is appreciated,
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can overwrite the function with `window.magnify = () => {};` since it's a global.

```js
// ==UserScript==
// @name        NewScript-kp6ekq7m
// @description This is your new file, start writing code
// @match       *://hibid.com/*
// @inject-into page
// ==/UserScript==

window.magnify = () => {};
```